# How to add a title over my columns headers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

I'm trying to create an XLS file with ExcelJs with two sheets. I want both sheets to have a "title" on the first line (the same title for both sheets) and then a bunch of columns with headers and values.
I've tried the `headerFooter` option when creating my sheets and I've tried to insert a row before creating my columns. Neither worked as my columns headers still appear on the first row.
There is this similar question on here : [Add rows before the column header using excel.js module + node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830513/add-rows-before-the-column-header-using-excel-js-module-node?rq=3) But it's rather old and the answers don't seem to work neither when looking at the various comments.

Is there any (clean) way to do this basic thing with ExcelJs ?